# How can I serialize a class from a Spring project to Redis, to later deserialize the class to a Guice project?

Tags: java, spring, redis, guice

I would like to serialize a class object inside my project which is using Spring RedisTemplate, with some serializer, to a Redis database so that I could later deserialize it within another project using Guice and some serializer (and **no** Spring dependencies). Is there some sleek/good way to do this?

I would like to be able to run a server on the Spring side and connect to it with light weight Guice workers that don't come with all the Spring overhead. The workers should be able to get from and put/set to the server hosted by the Spring server.

Reading from the Redis database feels complicated since RedisTemplate does things automatically, but it seems like reading and deserializing on the Guice side has to now be done manually, negating many of the the benefits of using Spring and Guice.

I am a rather inexperienced developer intern and I have been given a relatively large project to work with (somewhat alone), it can be a bit overwhelming at times. A good solution on how to get the Spring, Redis and Guice to work together would be much appreciated.

```
// This is just a very abstract example of a way I'd like things to work in the end
// Also I didn't write out the serializers here to avoid
// a cluttered question, but their implementation is very important. 

// Spring side

// A class to be serialized and deserialized
@RedisHash("foo")
public class Foo {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Set<SomeClass> someClassFiles;

    public getSomeClassFiles(){
        return this.someClassFiles;
}

@Service
GenericRedisService{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("template")
    private RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private SerializerService serializer;

    @Override
    public void put(String queue, Serializable object){
        String message = this.serializer.serialize(object);
        Long queueSize = this.redisTemplate.opsForList().rightPush(queue, message);
}

// Guice side

// A class to be serialized and deserialized
public class Foo {
    private String id;
    private Set<SomeClass> someClassFiles;

    public getSomeClassFiles(){
        return this.someClassFiles;
}

public class GenericRedisService{
    private final RedisService service;

    private final SerializerService serializer;

    @Override
    public Serializable get(String queue) {
        String message = this.redisService.blpop(3, queue);
        return this.serializer.deserialize(message);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of serializing the whole class? If it is just about transferring data then I think it is better to simply perform a simple JSON serialization/deserialization by a library like **Jackson** or **GSON**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Jackson serialization most certainly is a good solution if I can get it to work (as far as I know it's not Spring dependent). The objects need to remain in intact since they are then further transferred to another client.

Right now I serialize the object via ObjectMapper it gets mapped into a key value map that then I don't know how to turn into a new version of the object on the other side without mapping all the values to a new object. So I wonder if there is a way to serialize on one end and deserialize on the other. There are many different objects to serialize.

Comment: A workaround for this you can put all objects that need to be serialized/deserialized into a separate project and make a common dependency on both server and worker app. Thus you can deserialize them to the same type of objects in worker apps. You may consider using **Maven** or **Gradle** depending on your choice in order to manage dependency projects easily.